# Probability formula in machine learning

Tags: probability

I am reading Andrew Ng's notes on machine learning. I encountered a difficulty in notes#5, page 7: https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes5.pdf

[here's the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXRmt.png)

I struggle to understand how it is derived. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand equation 1 on page 7?

Comment: yes i do understand